# where does the glibc's implementation of syscall open set ENAMETOOLONG errno when pathname is too long?

Tags: c, system-calls, errno

From the man open:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);

...

       ENAMETOOLONG
              pathname was too long.
```

I couldn't find the assignment of `errno` to `ENAMETOOLONG` in the source code of glibc's open function. It is possible that this assignment is done by invoking kernel functions, but I couldn't find any evidence of that either.

Here are the functions I have already explored in glibc:

```c
/* Open FILE with access OFLAG.  If O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is in OFLAG,
   a third argument is the file protection.  */
int
__libc_open (const char *file, int oflag)
{
  int mode;

  if (file == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  if (__OPEN_NEEDS_MODE (oflag))
    {
      va_list arg;
      va_start(arg, oflag);
      mode = va_arg(arg, int);
      va_end(arg);
    }

  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
```

```c
int
__open_nocancel (const char *file, int oflag, ...)
{
  int mode = 0;

  if (__OPEN_NEEDS_MODE (oflag))
    {
      va_list arg;
      va_start (arg, oflag);
      mode = va_arg (arg, int);
      va_end (arg);
    }

  return INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL (openat, AT_FDCWD, file, oflag, mode);
}
```

```c
/* Open FILE with access OFLAG.  Interpret relative paths relative to
   the directory associated with FD.  If O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is in OFLAG, a
   third argument is the file protection.  */
int
__openat (int fd, const char *file, int oflag, ...)
{
  int mode;

  if (file == NULL)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return -1;
    }

  if (fd != AT_FDCWD && file[0] != '/')
    {
      /* Check FD is associated with a directory.  */
      struct stat64 st;
      if (__fxstat64 (_STAT_VER, fd, &st) != 0)
    return -1;

      if (!S_ISDIR (st.st_mode))
    {
      __set_errno (ENOTDIR);
      return -1;
    }
    }

  if (__OPEN_NEEDS_MODE (oflag))
    {
      va_list arg;
      va_start (arg, oflag);
      mode = va_arg (arg, int);
      va_end (arg);

      ignore_value (mode);
    }

  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
```

```c
/* Issue a syscall defined by syscall number plus any other argument
   required.  Any error will be handled using arch defined macros and errno
   will be set accordingly.
   It is similar to INLINE_SYSCALL macro, but without the need to pass the
   expected argument number as second parameter.  */
#define INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL(...) \
  __INLINE_SYSCALL_DISP (__INLINE_SYSCALL, __VA_ARGS__)

#define SYSCALL_CANCEL(...) \
  ({                                         \
    long int sc_ret;                                 \
    if (SINGLE_THREAD_P)                             \
      sc_ret = INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL (__VA_ARGS__);                \
    else                                     \
      {                                      \
    int sc_cancel_oldtype = LIBC_CANCEL_ASYNC ();                \
    sc_ret = INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL (__VA_ARGS__);              \
        LIBC_CANCEL_RESET (sc_cancel_oldtype);                   \
      }                                      \
    sc_ret;                                  \
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's handled by the filesystem because the rules for what names are too long could be very complex and file-system specific. See, for example, [this code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/namei.c#L1682) from EXT4.

Comment: fail enough, thanks! One more question: how does `open` invoke filesystem functions like ext4_lookup here?

Comment: @陳力: Very roughly: The kernel has structs of function pointers for each file system. For example, a function pointer struct for ext4 is built [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/fs/ext4/namei.c#L4005). Through several layers of indirection, the [open syscall](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/fs/open.c#L1110) at some point calls these functions, e.g. [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/fs/namei.c#L3203). (I'm not sure about some of the details, but that's the general idea.)